# PHPs variable scoping

Tags: php

This might seem as a trivial question, but since I just realised this after using php for about 8months, I think it requires some attention. I am used to strongly-typed languages such as java, but I do like weakly-typed languages as well(somehow).

Ok, so to the question in mind, I am defining a variable within a function, within a 3rd level  foreach loop. Something like

```
for($x =0; $x <= 20; $x++){
   for($x =0; $x <= 5; $x++){
      foreach($arr as $var){
        $new_arr = $var;
      }
       
      if(isset($new_arr)){
         //code executes here     
      }

   }
}
```

In the above example, the last if condition does return true, even though the $new var is not declared as a global variable, so how would it be accessible outside the foreach loop?
Shouldn't it give an undefined error ?

nb.I have already looked at the [php doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: php does not have a local scope for `if`, `foreach` etc.. All variables declared in those are considered as local to the entire function..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Much like javascript, PHP's variables are scoped to a function level. So your variable will return true for isset() in any foreach,for or while loop after it has been set. PHP doesn't have any concept of loop scoping.

It's also worth mentioning that the function scoping is a little stricter than javascript's. Without using the use () statement closures with a function don't have access to the calling function's context:

```
function ScopeOne() {
    $myVar = "hello";
    $scopeTwo = function () {
        return isset($myVar);
    };

    $doesScopeTwoHaveAccessToScopeOne = $scopeTwo();

    if ($doesScopeTwoHaveAccessToScopeOne) {
        echo "this won't be true";
    } else {
        echo "Scope Two can not access variables in scope one";
    }
}

ScopeOne();
```

Answer (score 5):

> even though the $new var is not declared as a global variable, so how
>   would it be accessible outside the foreach loop?

You are assuming `foreach` as a function, A `foreach` is not a function, but a language construct.

**A variable that has been assigned a value inside control structures will not be affected by scope issues , Even the innermost control structure can access it. !**

The `isset` checks whether the variable has been assigned a value or not.  So when you reach your innermost `foreach` the value will be assigned , so when you do the `isset` obviously it will return `true`.

Comment: Yes ofcourse the foreach is not a function. Assuming the for loops are wrapped inside a function. In java, a variable defined in a loop, would loose its scope if not defined outside the loop..

Comment: Nope the variable will not be affected by scope issues if it is inside a `for` , `foreach` , `if` ... (under control-structures)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! the answer I was looking for was the one which explained how php does not have loop scoping! I will mark yours as helpful but Steve B's as the answer since it was exactly what I wanted. thanks a heaps for the effort put into explanation though! cheers

Comment: @user2678538, Seems like you didn't read the content which I put under the bold text regarding the `isset`.

Comment: I have read it, as well as I did know how isset is used. In java the  compiler won't let you define variables and use them before they were assigned a value. Equivalent to isset, in java you would do `if(new_arr != null)`.